# Is it possible to use td elements inside div (without table)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create very flexible grid, my code is approximately as

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <td class="grid-cell">TEST</td>
    <td class="grid-cell">TEST</td>
    <td class="grid-cell">TEST</td>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I have problems:

1. If I am using `td` elements inside row, then CSS class styles are not applied sometimes. Styles are applied in React environment, but are not applied in JSFiddle pure Bootstrap environment.
2. If I am suing `div` elements inside row, then those div elements are not positioned in one line but each div is in separate line inside the greater div (row) element.

So - is it possible (advisable) to use td elements inside div and without table elements? And if not, then how can I organize div elements (belonging to one row) in one row/line?

This question is related to my other question (there is the links to JSFiddle code as well):
[Container div that contains scrollable table and that fills all the client area and that removes page scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703433/container-div-that-contains-scrollable-table-and-that-fills-all-the-client-area)

Comment: For the second problem, you should know that `div` elements will most likely to be on separate lines. If you want them to act like one in front of another until there's enough space in the same line, you should use `span`. And for the first problem, why do you even need `td`?! Why don't you just use normal tags like `div` and `span`? It's much more clean and efficient

Answer (score 1):

Use a list element and set the child elements to inline..
Set `list-style-type` to none to remove the bulletpoints markers.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  TEST
  </li>
  <li>
  TEST
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, your div issue.. that's divs desired behaviour since a div is a block element compared to span which is an inline-block element. You should either use spans or set div to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a table layout then use `display:table`

```css
.grid {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid-row {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST</div>
  </div>
   <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST Test</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```