# Make all child divs with the same index in sibling parents same height

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/16region/jmktr28g/31/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, deleniti in.</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, deleni</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, delenit</div>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a..</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like table (and I can't use tables). So bottom border of each prop-item is at the same level. I am not sure which approach to choose for jquery.

Comment: you don't need to use table, simply use `display:table` here is an idea : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704905/8620333

Comment: Is it possible to change the HTML-code? If so, CSS grids can be an approach. Might be nice to avoid JavaScript if it's not needed.

Comment: @Tibbelit not, the html cannot be changes unfortunately

Comment: @kulan, see my answer below

Comment: @Tibbelit well, as long as it works.

Comment: @kulan, if you're happy with my answer below, would you mind to accept it? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the prettiest solution, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/59p07t1u/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($(`.prop-item`), function(i) {
    var h = 0;
    $.each($(`.prop-item:nth-child(${i})`), function() {
      h = $(this).height() > h ? $(this).height() : h;
    });
    $(`.prop-item:nth-child(${i})`).css("height", h);
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item-block {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.prop-item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, deleniti in.</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, deleni</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a. Alias distinctio optio odio maxime nihil, delenit</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="props">
      <div class="prop-item">ugit magnam at, beatae ducimus, maiores, voluptas minus cumque quos est officiis a..</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="prop-item"> consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum f</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="prop-item">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the child at a specific index like this:

```
.prop-item:nth-child(1) {
  height:70px;
}
.prop-item:nth-child(2) {
  height:60px;
}
.prop-item:nth-child(3) {
  height:80px;
}
.prop-item:nth-child(4) {
  height:90px;
}
```

I think what you really want is to make them the same height as the box with the longest content, but that will involve JavaScript.

UPDATE:

I tried to solve it with CSS Grid, and I think I created a solution you can use.  It requires you to flatten your HTML a bit so that you just have a container and the child items, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item a-1">
  <div class="item a-2">
  <div class="item b-1">
  <div class="item b-2">
</div>
```

The CSS is very simple:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

I added identifier classes simply for referencing the items in the grid for superficial styling purposes.

Here's my JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/stap8Lw7/

Comment: Yes that's what i need to do. The content will be dynamic, so i can't target specific index.

Comment: using TABLE would make it so much easier. can you explain why you cannot use TABLE?

Comment: It's going to be a carousel slider.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery, you can write some like that:

```
var heights = [];
$('.props').each(function(){
  $(this).children().each(function(i){
    heights[i] = heights[i] || 0;
    heights[i] = Math.max(heights[i], this.clientHeight);
  });
  $(this).children().each(function(i){
    $(this).height(heights[i]);
  });
});
```

But i strong recommend use CSS to work around the problem; maybe you can use flex to solve it.